# How to do infinite scrolling w/ Polymer.dart's core-list-dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

Previously, I did a `<template repeat="{{item in viewModel.items}}">`, but w/ `core-list-dart` I understand that it will repeat what's in its `<template>` for every item in the list passed to its `data` attribute. So I do `<core-list-dart id="list" data="{{viewModel.items}}" height="80">` but I get nothing inside it, and no error reported. I'm suspecting that `viewModel.items` is not returning what it expects, and that it's not working like it did with the template repeat?

As well, if `core-list` is all about infinite lists, why does the demo not even seem to be infinite (i.e. show more and more based on scrolling)? It seems to just print the whole list out, though IIRC it used to be infinite.

References:

- https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/demo.html
- https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/tree/master/web/core_list_dart

Comment: Can you post more of what you are passing to core-list. Are the rows there but just blank? The main trick I found is that it won't be item.foo anymore just foo when you reference fields.

Comment: Right, I did reference it as just foo.

Comment: Hey @Anders, my commented out attempt, with the working code using regular method for context. https://github.com/woven/dart-communities/blob/master/lib/src/client/components/inbox_list/inbox_list.html#L10 Does this help? I feel like I'll get a lot of benefits w/ `core-list`.